# iOS swift remoteControlReceivedWithEvent

Tags: ios, swift

This is not working in my AppDelegate.swift :

```
override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) {
    if event.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl {
        if event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay {
            println("received remote play")
            ViewController.sharedInstance.play() 
        } else if event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause {
            println("received remote pause")
            ViewController.sharedInstance.pause2() 
        } else if event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlTogglePlayPause {
            println("received toggle")
            ViewController.sharedInstance.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

from above code this part is not working:

```
ViewController.sharedInstance.pause2()
```

Although I can see 'received remote pause' being printed

My ViewControl.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

static let sharedInstance = ViewController()

func pause2() {

        BackgroundAudio2.pause()

        BackgroundAudio3.pause()

        BackgroundAudio4.pause()

        BackgroundAudio5.pause()

        BackgroundAudio6.pause()

        BackgroundAudio7.pause()

        BackgroundAudio8.pause()

        BackgroundAudio9.pause()

    isPlaying = false
}
```

Everything in the app works fine except events  in remoteControlReceivedWithEvent

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your first responder is ViewController but you expect code to be run in AppDelegate. I think this should be in one view. Also to become first responder you should do self.becomeFirstResponder()